# sum up numbers between a range using class

Tags: java

I have written a program with the method `getSum(int lower, int upper)`, which returns the sum of the numbers between the lower and the upper bound (inclusive).

```
public class Main {

    int lower; 
    int upper;

    public void getSum(int lower, int upper){

        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=upper;i<=lower; i++){
            System.out.println("the total sum is "+ sum);
            sum = sum+1;
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Main main = new Main();
        main.getSum(20, 50);
    }
}
```

I expect the answer 1085, and to see all the numbers printed as I add them up, but I get nothing printed at all. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you're just adding 1 to the sum every iteration...

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite your `for` loop:

1. Your initial value for `i`, and your limit test, are both wrong
2. You need to add `i` to `sum` not `1`

Sample:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=lower;i<=upper; i++){
    sum = sum+i;
    System.out.println("the total sum is "+ sum);
}
```

Note that this can be solved (assuming no arithmentic overflow occurs for large input numbers or ranges) without iterating using the equation:

```
sum = (upper - lower + 1) * (lower + upper) / 2;
```

As an extra tip,

- you could do `sum += i` instead of `sum = sum + i`
- your assignments of the `lower` and `upper` parameter values to the class fields with `this.lower = lower` are unnecessary; you could remove them with no impact on your method
- you should move your `println` statement to print the sum after it is incremented
- you should consider returning `sum` as the method's output:

Sample:

```
public int getSum(int lower, int upper){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=lower;i<=upper; i++){
        sum += i;
        System.out.println("the total sum is "+ sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I just double checked , it runs smoothly but the sum right now while compiling goes up till 1035, its not getting the range between them.

Comment: @MasnadHossain. This method will return the sum of all numbers between and including `lower` and `upper`. You haven't clearly defined any other behaviour. If you want a different output then you need to define it in your question. What result do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding only 1 to sum as pointed by others

you can change your method to

```
public void getSum(int lower, int upper){

    this.lower = lower;
    this.upper = upper;

     int sum = 0;

    for(int i=lower;i<=upper; i++){
       System.out.println("the total sum is "+ sum);
       sum +=i;

}
System.out.println("the final total sum is "+ sum);
}
```

### DEMO

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this simple way:

```
public static int getSum(int lower, int upper) {
    if (lower > upper)
        return 0;
    else
        return lower + getSum(lower + 1, upper);
}
```

or, shorter:

```
public static int getSum(int lower, int upper) {
    return lower > upper ? 0 : lower + getSum(lower + 1, upper);
}
```

Then, in your `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The sum is " + getSum(10, 11));
}
```

Comment: the total sum is 199989810

Comment: @MasnadHossain. Recursion like this is fine, but there is a limit to it. For a large enough range between `lower` and `upper`, this method will cause a fatal exception, called a `StackOverflowException`, which will terminate your program. The exact stack depth that causes this depends on your JVM.